# flutter audio_service and just_audio is not working with navigation on iOS

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio, audio-service

I have project with audio_service and just_audio. It is working fine on Android. But It is not working on iOS. I found out that it is happening because of the navigation route.

I have attached the example project. [Example](https://github.com/alexaung/audio_service_routing)

If I call the Player screen at home, it is playing. If I call the home screen first then there is button to call the Player screen. If user click the player screen show but song is not playing. It is showing loading indicator.

Do you know why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try to stop the service before the init.
audio_service.stop()
audio_service.init()
As there is some issue with latest iOS update in audio_service and it will be fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks for comment. After I change the example from audio_service, it is working. I have no idea what is happen the above code. I will test with your suggestion later and let you know.